# Scrapy unable to login

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

[i have check formdata also](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFU8D.png)im not able to login in to the website . website doesn't contain any token or hidden variables . 
please proper example or tell me how to resolve the error.
after the post call it return the same login page html.
i have tried with wrong username and password still same response.

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    start_urls = ['http://schedule.amacotton.com/']
    LOGIN_URL = 'http://schedule.amacotton.com/login.php'
    URL = 'http://schedule.amacotton.com/transportation.php'

    def parse(self, response):
        my_data = {'user': 'abc', 'pass': 'abc', 'plant': '1','login':'Login'}
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response= response,
            formdata= my_data,
            callback=self.scrap_page,
        )

    def scrap_page(self, response):
        print response.body
```

output:

```
    2018-02-27 14:41:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET             http://schedule.amacotton.com/> (referer: None)
    2018-02-27 14:41:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST    http://schedule.amacotton.com/login.php> (referer: http://schedule.amacotton.com   /)

     <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head><title>
        Login
    </title></head>
    <body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="login.php" id="form1">
    <div>
        <table width="250" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>UserName:</td>
                <td><input name="user" type="text" id="user" style="width:100px;" /></td>
                <td rowspan="2"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" id="login" tabindex="5" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input name="pass" type="password" id="pass" style="width:100px;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <span id="lblErrorConfirmation" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:small; color:Red; padding-left: 10px"></span>
        <br />
        <table id="lstPlants" border="0">
        <tr>
                <td><input id="lstPlants_0" type="radio" name="plant" value="1" /><label for="lstPlants_0">Amarillo Cotton Warehouse</label></td>
        </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="lstPlants_1" type="radio" name="plant" value="2" /><label for="lstPlants_1">Tulia</label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>



    2018-02-27 14:41:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that login did not succeed? I just checked that page and invalid login page looks nothing like the output you provided - there's no form there, just invalid login information. Maybe the website doesn't redirect user anywhere after successful login?

I think you should actually go to URL you want to scrap after the login:

```
import scrapy

class ExampleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'example'
    start_urls = ['http://schedule.amacotton.com/']
    LOGIN_URL = 'http://schedule.amacotton.com/login.php'
    URL = 'http://schedule.amacotton.com/transportation.php'

    def parse(self, response):
        my_data = {'user': 'abc', 'pass': 'abc', 'plant': '1','login':'Login'}
        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response= response,
            formdata= my_data,
            callback=self.open_page,
        )

    def open_page(self, response):
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=self.URL,
            callback=self.scrap_page
        )

    def scrap_page(self, response):
        print response.body
```

Comment: 2018-02-27 17:22:42 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://schedule.amacotton.com/login.php> from <GET http:/
/schedule.amacotton.com/transportation.php>
2018-02-27 17:22:42 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (407) <GET http://schedule.amacotton.com/login.php> (referer: http://schedule.amacotton.com/lo
gin.php)
when i gave right username and password...output is follows   2018-02-27 17:22:42 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <407 http://schedule.amacotton.com/login.php>: HTTP status code is no
t handled or not allowed

Comment: When i did with right credential also 302 redirect issue came

Comment: After the successful login it has to redirect to http://schedule.amacotton.com/transportation.php this page..